# How to wire this pogo pin header strip

Tags: connector, wiring, pogo-pins

manufacturer number (Mill-Max): 855-22-010-10-001101 [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2625425.pdf?_ga=2.233789398.957003990.1596612858-743403225.1588747121) (2x5 pins)

[image]

Can I directly solder something to the bottom pins ? The manufacturer has some solutions but it requires expensiv tools which I don't want to buy. What could be a good solution ?

Comment: When you say the bottom pins are you referring to the .016 DIA. side or the .019 DIA? As this is a spring-loaded connector you are only meant to solder to the .016 DIA side, and that’s just a basic through hole solder joint.

Comment: @JackSoldano The .016 DIA

Comment: You could probably point to point wire it but mechanical support and durability may be limited without a PCB.  In a pinch for short term use you might wire it, test it, and glue it into some 3d printed piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can solder to the .016 DIA side of the connector no problem, this part is meant to be inserted into a Plated (Non-plated would work too) Through Hole PCB slot then soldered.

I'm not sure what the Manufacturer solution would be other than a development breakout PCB?

Comment: I wonder if the OP is thinking they are swage (https://www.mill-max.com/engineering-notebooks/introduction-to-swage-assembly)... which these are not.

Comment: @vicatcu that could make sense, yeah the ones OP are talking about are much easier to deal with

Answer (score 0):

Actually you solder the bottom part to a PCB, through hole. The upper pins have springs and they are meant to make a non permanent contact by touching contact pads.